# How to transition from approximation of odd function using $\sin$ and $\cos$ to only using $\sin$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, even-and-odd-functions

I'm failing to understand the following transition:

Given that $f$ is an odd function defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$, we know that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$||f-\sum_{n=0}^Na_n \sin(nx)+b_n\cos(nx)||_\infty<\epsilon$$

(where this is the sup norm, i.e. max value in $[-\pi,\pi]$ in this case),

**then** for all $\epsilon$ there exist $a_n$ such that:

$$\max_{[0,\pi]} \big|f-\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \sin(nx)\big|<\epsilon$$

This transition is supposed to rely on the fact that both $f$ and $\sin$ are odd functions somehow, but I just can't see how to prove this (this should be simple, from my gathering, so it can't be a matter of being familiar with complicated trigonometric identities etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it is an odd function, the $b_n$ will be $0$ if you have calculated the Fourier coefficients in the usual way

Comment: @FShrike I don't yet have Fourier coefficients since at this point we hadn't yet learned it. We only have Stone-Weierstrass and the resulting approximation using polynomials and trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: Even if you don’t know how to calculate Fourier coefficients, the fact that $f$ is odd and cosine is even must surely imply that all the $b_n$ are zero.

Comment: @bubba I agree - I do understand this intuitively, but I cannot justify this formally.